# Is there any reason to target the defensive riders?

Tags: road-redemption

There are some riders on the road (they always seem to be neutral as well) who have little icons floating over their heads.  Most of them give easily identifiable bonuses for killing them.  For example, the **$** guy gives you cash, the **+** guy gives you health.

One of these riders has what looks like a little shield over his head.  Additionally, these defensive riders will parry 100% of your melee attacks, so they have to be killed either with explosives, firearms, or via environmental kill.  *Critical strikes* also seem to work, as they are unblockable.

Is there any reason for me to go after these guys like for the other bonus riders, or are they just more dangerous agents that should be avoided?

[image: Guy with shield over his head]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to target defensive riders specifically in terms of reward like there is for money or health riders. However, there may still be reasons to take them out:

- they're in the way of you killing someone specific, e.g. there's a money rider next to them and they'll block your attacks
- you're being attacked by a group and don't have nitro to boost out
- every kill gives you money and experience, including of defensive riders

I'd also like to add that there's another way to kill them: block one of their attacks and strike back, they can't block your counterattack. Still, if you meet one alone on the road like in your screenshot, it's fine to just avoid them.

Comment: I've found they block my counterattacks as well.  Is it possible I'm just not attacking fast enough?

Comment: It's possible, the window to attack after blocking isn't too long. Next time you find a solitary defensive rider again, test it by staying besides them until they attack, block and immediately counter. If it works, it's just your timing that's off. In my experience, while you don't have to attack instantly to the point that it's a test of reflexes, if you just sway to the side a bit before you come back into range and strike, that's already too slow.